# How to invert digits in Kattis - Add 'Em Up?

Tags: java, algorithm

[image]

This image describes the [Add Em Up!](https://open.kattis.com/problems/addemup) question from Kattis I was about to solve. Give me some ideas that I could employ while doing it.

I am stuck at how to edit such that the 2 or 5 can be inverted in an integer form.

How can I change a number 1223 or 152 whereby I can replace 2 by 5 or 5 by 2 so it becomes 1523 or 1553 and 125 or 122?

Comment: When you turn a card, what was up is down, and what was left is right. Of course, not all turns produce a valid number! Turning "1223" does not produce a valid number; if you turn "152", you get "251". Write down card numbers on a piece of paper and try turning it around. It has certainly helped me! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem description on this one is unclear. It seems like it's asking you to rotate the cards as you would physically, which entails replacing 6s and 9s, but that replacement never seems to be tested. You can get away with simply reversing the digits in the numbers.

To make matters worse, there's no sample test case with a 3, 4 or 7, which have no sensible representation in flipped form. Intuitively, these flips should be disregarded, and that intuition turns out to be true in the Kattis test suite.

Another edge case is what to do about 10 or 2100. These reverse to 1 and 12 respectively and shouldn't be ignored.

> I am stuck at how to edit such that the 2 or 5 can be inverted in an integer form.

After spinning a card physically, 2 stays 2 and 5 stays 5. Only 6 and 9 would change values on a flip, and Kattis doesn't test those at this time. 2 and 5 mirror each other horizontally, but that's not relevant here.

After clarifying the requirements, the problem pretty much boils down to [two sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) with a reversal tossed in on certain numbers:

- Create an empty lookup table
- For each number in the input:

  - If `lookup.contains(targetSum - newInputValue)`, then you found a sum
  - Otherwise, if 3, 4 and 7 aren't present in the string, do the following:

    - Produce the "flipped" value of the number by either operating on the digits or reversing the number as a string
    - If `lookup.contains(targetSum - newInputValueFlipped)`, then you found a sum
    - Add the flipped value to the lookup table
  - Add the new input value to the lookup table

An "obvious" optimization is to cache each completed flip in a lookup table but it's not necessary to pass the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that number into string first

```
String str = "" + 123
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(str);
```

Build a if condition inside a for loop and check for the given num 2 or 5 then replace the given number.

```
myName.setCharAt(i, '5');
```